# CSS path issues magento 2 installation

Tags: php, css, magento2, magento-1.4, magento-2.0

After installing magento 2.1, css is not loading and it is showing version number in css path which results in 404. See below url:

```
http://exapmle.com/pub/static/version1497424536/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css
```

instead of above it should be

http://exapmle.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css

I have followed all steps i.e. upgrade, compile and static content deploy. Also apache configuration is fine and allowoverride is all there

Answer (score 0):

Try this Before that take Backup

Remove everything, except .htaccess file from pub/static folder

Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” and replace to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Note: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except .htaccess file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/